# Fatorial de 0 a 20 usando For

Tags: c, for, fatorial

Preciso fazer o seguinte exercício: 
"Utilizando o loop for, calcule e imprima em tela o fatorial
de todos os números entre 0 e 20. Utilize o tipo Double. Ex: 0! =1
1! =1
2! = 2
... 20! = 2432902008176640000"
Mas não consigo identificar o erro que estou cometendo.
Alguém tem uma ideia?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int cc, cf, acc;
    double fat;

    for(cc=0; cc<=20; cc++){
        if(cc==0) fat=1;
        else{
            for(cf=0;cf<cc;cf++){

                fat = fat * cf;
                acc = acc + fat;
            }
        }
        printf("%d! = %.1lf\n",cc+1 , fat);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Você está somando "int" com "double":

```
acc = acc + fat;
```

O problema é que valores altos de fatorial cabem em double, mas não cabem em int.
Aliás, você nem está usando a variável "acc" para nada...

(2) Você não está inicializando a variável "acc":

```
  int cc, cf, acc;
```

Isto é, mesmo ignorando que acc deveria ser double, e que você não está usando acc para nada, suas contas com acc resultam em valor indefinido, porque acc não foi inicializado.

(3) Sua lógica está ineficiente e confusa:

```
for (cc = 0; cc <= 20; cc++)
{
  if (cc == 0) // <------- INEFICIENTE, está repetindo a mesma comparação
    fat = 1;   // <------- 21 vezes, sendo que só 1 vez ela vai ser verdadeira
  else
  {
    for (cf = 0; cf < cc; cf++) // <---- CONFUSO: por que este segundo loop ???
    {
      fat = fat * cf;
      acc = acc + fat;
    }
  }
```

(4) Seu programa não está documentado. Você não colocou nem UM comentário explicando sua lógica.

Abaixo, uma versão simplificada do programa.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int cc;
  double fat = 1;

  // caso especial: 0! = 1
  printf("* 0! = 1\n");

  // caso geral: n! = 1 * 2 * .. * n
  for (cc = 1; cc <= 20; cc++)
  {
    fat *= cc;
    printf("* %d! = %.0lf\n", cc , fat);
  } // for

  return 0;
}
```

Teste:

```
$ 380272.exe                      
* 0! = 1                          
* 1! = 1                          
* 2! = 2                          
* 3! = 6                          
* 4! = 24                         
* 5! = 120                        
* 6! = 720                        
* 7! = 5040                       
* 8! = 40320                      
* 9! = 362880                     
* 10! = 3628800                   
* 11! = 39916800                  
* 12! = 479001600                 
* 13! = 6227020800                
* 14! = 87178291200               
* 15! = 1307674368000             
* 16! = 20922789888000            
* 17! = 355687428096000           
* 18! = 6402373705728000          
* 19! = 121645100408832000        
* 20! = 2432902008176640000       
$
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá, tudo bem?
Você pode fazer em C da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   double fat;
   int n;
   printf("Insira um valor para o qual deseja calcular seu fatorial: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   for(fat = 1; n > 1; n = n - 1)
     fat = fat * n;

   printf("\nFatorial calculado: %lf", fat);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu faria algumas alterações estruturais e de lógica no seu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int cc, cf, acc;
  long fat; // <1>

  for (cc = 0; cc <= 20; cc++) {
    fat = 1; // <2>
    if (cc == 0) fat = 1;
    else {
      for (cf = 1; cf <= cc; cf++) { // <3>
        fat *= cf; // <4>
      }
    }
    printf("%d! = %ld\n", cc, fat); // <5>
  }
}
```

<1> Primeiro que eu mudaria o type da variável para `long`, que é muito superior ao de um simples `int`, e levando em consideração que não existe multiplicação de números inteiros com resultado com casas decimais, não vejo problema em exibir como inteiro.

```
╔════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════════╦════════════╗
║ Type   ║ Storage size ║ Value range          ║ Precision  ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════╣
║ float  ║ 4 byte       ║ 1.2E-38 to 3.4E+38   ║ 6 decimal  ║
║ double ║ 8 byte       ║ 2.3E-308 to 1.7E+308 ║ 15 decimal ║
╚════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════════╩════════════╝
```

<2> Cada iteração do segundo for é necessário zerar a variável.

<3> O segundo for é necessário iniciar de 1 para não existir a primeira multiplicação por 0 que zera o resultado final, na verdade é aqui que está o problema lógico do seu código.

<4> Resumiria a operação matemática.

<5> O `printf` eu exibiria usando `%ld` que em outra palavras pode ser lido como `long double`.

---

O resultado final pode ser visto em qualquer [compilador C online](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php):

```
0! = 1
1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
6! = 720
7! = 5040
8! = 40320
9! = 362880
10! = 3628800
11! = 39916800
12! = 479001600
13! = 6227020800
14! = 87178291200
15! = 1307674368000
16! = 20922789888000
17! = 355687428096000
18! = 6402373705728000
19! = 121645100408832000
20! = 2432902008176640000
```